# Counting Sheep (Beatrix Trotter) Javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, runtime, infinite-loop

I am trying to solve a question on CodeWars that was part of the Google CodeJam 2016 qualification rounds.
https://www.codewars.com/kata/bleatrix-trotter-the-counting-sheep/train/javascript

I believe my code accounts for all test cases, my only issue is that it cannot be submitted on codewars because it has a runtime greater than 12000 ms.

How Can I make my Code more efficient?? also is there a best practice for testing whether the loop will be infinite.

```
function trotter(n) {
  var tracker = [];
  var sum = [];
  var snacker = n;
  for(var i = 0; tracker.length < 10; i++){
    sum = snacker.toString().split('');
    sum.forEach(function(num) {
        if (tracker.indexOf(num) == -1) {
             tracker.push(num);
        }
    });
    snacker += n;
  }
  return tracker.length === 10 ? snacker - n : "INSOMNIA";
}
```

Comment: *for* loops can be faster than *forEach*, and *if..else* is usually faster than the compound operator `? :`, and storing the value of `tracker.length ` is faster than getting it every time. But of course compiler optimisations mean that isn't always true.

Comment: I will make the adjustments you have just mentioned and see if it works, thank you

Comment: I have tried to make this as efficient as I can with map and reduce but I was not able to achieve the same return value;

Comment: If n == 2 you won't get a "3" in 10 or fewer iterations.

Comment: the instructions in the link I posted to codwars specify that n may only increase by multiplying by increments of 1.

Comment: 2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26,28,*30*.  The assert test for 2 states it expects the number of iterations to be 90/2 = 45.

Comment: Built-in methods like *map* and *reduce* are not necessarily any faster (or even much less code) that loops. They can be very concise though if combined with arrow functions and simple callbacks.

Comment: @GeorgeYammine Did anyone solve your problem? If so, could you please accept the best answer (click the checkmark under the points). That will help other users that come across your question quickly spot the accepted answer and it also gives 15 rep. points to the author (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When performance matters and reduced readability is not an issue you should:

- Prefer `for` and `while` loops rather than built-ins like `map`, `forEach`...
- In recent (2016) versions of `JavaScript`, it looks like `for` loops, specially reverse `for` loops, are the most performant option.

  Also, keep in mind that you don't need to use its 3 expressions. For example, for me...:

  ```
  let found = 0;

  for (;found < 10;) {
  ```

  and

  ```
  let j = chars.length;

  for (;j;) {
  ```

  consistently returned better results than the same with the initialisation in the initialisation slot and than `while` loops, although in this latter case the difference was not so big.

  For more one this, see [Javascript Performance: While vs For Loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18640032/javascript-performance-while-vs-for-loops)
- When using `foo.bar` in a `while`'s or `for`'s expression, such as `for (let i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)`, prefer to declare the limit condition above so that it is not evaluated each time, as that involves an [object lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917008/javascript-object-property-lookup):

  ```
  const totalElements = array.length;

  for (let i = 0; i < totalElements; ++i) { ... }
  ```
- Prefer pre-increment instead of post-increment. The latter will create a temporary variable storing the pre-incrementation value, which will return to you, while the former will first do the increment and then return the incremented value. No temporary variable needed.

  For more on this, see [post increment vs pre increment - Javascript Optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546981/post-increment-vs-pre-increment-javascript-optimization)

  Actually, if the result is going to be the same regardless which one you use, then I would advise you to use pre-increment whenever possible.
- Avoid built-in methods that have an equivalent expression. For example, `(n + '')` is more performant than `n.toString()`.
- Avoid type conversions and prefer using integers rather than floats or strings as modern JS engines tag variable types. That means that, on one hand, changing types will have a performance penalty, and, on the other hand, that using them consistently will allow the engine to do some type-specific optimisation.

  For more on this, see https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/v8/
- Use [bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) when possible. For example, an integer division can be done with `Math.floor(a  /b)` or with `a / b | 0`, which is almost twice as fast.

  For more on integer division in `JavaScript`, see this interesting thread: [How to perform integer division and get the remainder in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4228356/how-to-perform-integer-division-and-get-the-remainder-in-javascript)
- Prefer an object lookup (`object.prop` or `object['prop']`) rather than using `Array.prototype.indexOf(...)`.

  See [Javascript: what lookup is faster: array.indexOf vs object hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32234733/javascript-what-lookup-is-faster-array-indexof-vs-object-hash)
- Avoid using `arrays` and `objects` and related methods when there are alternatives with simpler structures or inmutable data structures.

  For example, @RobG's solution uses `splice`. While I'm not aware of the internal implementation, probably it is shifting the elements that come after the deleted ones to compact the array again and updating its `length` as well.

  With my solution, however, the `length` of the array is always the same and you are just changing its values from `false` to `true`, which involves much less overhead, as there's no need to reallocate space.
- Use typed arrays when possible, though I tried `Uint8Array` here, both assigning it `true` and `1`, and none of them improved the times; the former actually almost doubled the time and the first one kept them more or less the same. Maybe it there was a `BooleanArray` it could work.

Keep in mind this is just a list of some techniques or features I think may help to speed up your example. I highly recommend you to read the external links I added as well in order to better understand how and why they work and where else they can be applied.

Moreover, in general, the lower level you keep your code, that is, you using basic data types and operations, the most performance it will be.

To prove that, below I show you a highly optimised version of this code that uses integer division `(n / 10) | 0` and remainder (`%`).

```js
function trotter(N) {
  if (N === 0) return 'INSOMNIA';
  
  const digits = [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false];
    
  let n;
  let last = 0;
  let found = 0;
 
  for (;found < 10;) {
    n = last += N;
    
    for (;n;) {
      const digit = n % 10;
            
      n = (n / 10) | 0;
            
      if (!digits[digit]) {
        digits[digit] = true;
        
        ++found;
      }
    }
  }
  
  return last;
}

const numbers = [0, 2, 7, 125, 1625, 1692];
const outputs = ['INSOMNIA', 90, 70, 9000, 9750, 5076];

// CHECK IT WORKS FIRST:

numbers.map((number, index) => {
  if (trotter(number) !== outputs[index]) {
    console.log('EXPECTED = ' + outputs[index]);
    console.log('     GOT = ' + trotter(number));

    throw new Error('Incorrect value.');
  }
});


// PERF. TEST:

const ITERATIONS = 1000000;

const t0 = performance.now();

for (let i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; ++i) {
  numbers.map((number, index) => trotter(number));
}

const t1 = performance.now();

console.log(`AVG. TIME: ${ (t1 - t0) / ITERATIONS } ms. with ${ ITERATIONS } ITERATIONS`);
```

```
   AVG. TIME: 0.0033206450000000005 ms. with 1000000 ITERATIONS

     BROWSER: Google Chrome Version 59.0.3071.86 (Official Build) (64-bit)
          OS: macOS Sierra

BRAND, MODEL: MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)
   PROCESSOR: 2,8 GHz Intel Core i7
      MEMORY: 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
```

Below you can see my initial answer, which uses some of the other optimisations listed here, but still converts the `number` variable `n` to `string` and uses `String.prototype.split()` to get its digits.

It is almost 5 times slower then the one above!

```js
function trotter(N) {
  if (N === 0) return 'INSOMNIA';
  
  const digits = [false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false];
  
  let n = N;
  let i = 0;
  let found = 0;
  
  for (;found < 10;) {
    // There's no need for this multiplication:

    n = N * ++i;
    
    // Type conversion + Built-in String.prototype.split(), both can
    // be avoided:

    const chars = (n + '').split('');
    
    let j = chars.length;
    
    for (;j;) {
      const digit = chars[--j];
            
      if (!digits[digit]) {
        digits[digit] = true;
        
        ++found;
      }
    }
  }
  
  return n;
}

const numbers = [0, 2, 7, 125, 1625, 1692];
const outputs = ['INSOMNIA', 90, 70, 9000, 9750, 5076];

// CHECK IT WORKS FIRST:

numbers.map((number, index) => {
  if (trotter(number) !== outputs[index]) {
    console.log('EXPECTED = ' + outputs[index]);
    console.log('     GOT = ' + trotter(number));

    throw new Error('Incorrect value.');
  }
});


// PERF. TEST:

const ITERATIONS = 1000000;

const t0 = performance.now();

for (let i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; ++i) {
  numbers.map((number, index) => trotter(number));
}

const t1 = performance.now();

console.log(`AVG. TIME: ${ (t1 - t0) / ITERATIONS } ms. with ${ ITERATIONS } ITERATIONS`);
```

```
   AVG. TIME: 0.016428575000000004 ms. with 1000000 ITERATIONS

     BROWSER: Google Chrome Version 59.0.3071.86 (Official Build) (64-bit)
          OS: macOS Sierra

BRAND, MODEL: MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)
   PROCESSOR: 2,8 GHz Intel Core i7
      MEMORY: 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
```

Comment: @GeorgeYammine I updated my solution. The current one should be almost 5 times faster than the initial one.

Answer (score 0):

The following code has no special optimisations and uses all ECMA-262 ed 3 methods. It ran the full suite of tests in 339 ms.

```js
function trotter(n){
  var nums = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'];
  var i = 1;

  // Zero creates an infinite loop, so skip it
  if (n !== 0) {

    // While there are numbers to remove, keep going
    // Limit loops to 100 just in case
    while (nums.length && i < 100) {
      // Get test number as an array of digits
      var d = ('' + (n * i)).split('');

      // For each digit, if in nums remove it
      for (var j=0, jLen=d.length; j<jLen; j++) {
        var idx = nums.indexOf(d[j]);

        if (idx > -1) nums.splice(idx, 1);
      }

      i++;
    }
  }
  // If there are numbers left, didn't get to sleep
  // Otherwise, return last number seen (put d back together and make a numer)
  return nums.length? 'INSOMNIA' : Number(d.join(''));
}

console.log('0   : ' + trotter(0));
console.log('125 : ' + trotter(125));
console.log('1625: ' + trotter(1625));
```

Most cases are resolved in about 10 iterations, however 125, 1250, 12500, etc. take 73 iterations, which I think is the most that any number takes.

Since *Array* methods may be slow, here's a string version that's about [*twice as fast*](https://jsperf.com/trotter-tests/1):

```js
function trotter(n){
  var found = '';
  if (n !== 0) {
    var i = 1;
    while (found.length < 10) {
      var d = i * n + '';
      var j = d.length;
      while (j) {
        var c = d[--j];
        var idx = found.indexOf(c);
        if (idx == -1) found += c;
      }
      i++;
    }
  }
  return found.length == 10? +d : 'INSOMNIA';
}

[0,    // Infinte loop case
 125,  // Max loop case
 1625] // just a number
 .forEach(function (n) {
  console.log(n + ' : ' + trotter(n));
});
```

While doing `while (found.length)` is not optimal, it's typically only computed about 10 times, so not really significant to move outside the condition. An alternative is to include a counter that is incremented each time a digit is added to *found*, but this isn't really about optimising performance as much as finding something reasonable that works and passes the (undisclosed) tests at codewars.

Comment: BTW the tests passing time at codewars does not depend on your code. Every time they show a different unpredictable result.

Comment: May I  ask why you think my runtime is taking so long? even when I limited my iterations to 100 in my code It would still time out

Comment: There is nothing that stands out. You might try replacing *forEach* with a *for* loop (minimal code change) and see what the difference is. The limit of 100 iterations should never be reached with valid input, 73 was the largest I got with 125, 1250, etc. I tested up to 10,000,001, so not exhaustive but I think it gives a fairly high degree of confidence. I can't logically think of a number that should fail other than 0.

Comment: @RobG while you are right with the issues that you are pointing out, your code also suffers from multiple performance issues that could be improved. Particularly, I think you are abusing `Arrays`, specially using `indexOf` and `splice`.

Comment: Using the test setup in my answer, your code took an average of `0.03289369 ms.` to run.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```js
    function trotter(n){
      var unseen = '0123456789', last = 0;
      while (unseen != '' && last < 72*n) {
        last += n;
        var reg = new RegExp('[' + last + ']+', 'g');
        unseen = unseen.replace(reg, '');
      }
      return unseen != '' ? 'INSOMNIA' : last;
    };

    console.log('0   : ' + trotter(0));
    console.log('125 : ' + trotter(125));
    console.log('1625: ' + trotter(1625));
```

Comment: Using `RegExp` and `Array.prototype.replace` is a performance killer. I tried to measure your time running multiple iterations using the test setup in my answer and I had to kill the tab... :\